# Куда спрятать функцию C#?

Tags: c#

Есть функция которая проверяет привязку по железу, нужно её спрятать что бы при реверсе было сложнее отыскать. Нужно что бы она выполнялась при запуске программы. Событие на загрузку формы и в паблик функцию формы тоже не подходит, потому что слишком легко найти.

Comment: Спрячьте ее в нативный код

Comment: можно сделать компиляцию приложения в .Net native, но тогда программа будет доступна только на Windows 10, это не очень подходит

Comment: `Нативный код` != `.Net Native`

Comment: @Zergatul, тогда встанет вопрос как спрятать ее вызов))))

Comment: @Zergatul а можно, пожалуйста, подробнее про то, как вставить кусок нативного кода в .NET приложение? Или хотя бы ссылкочку какую-нибудь

Comment: @Zergatul а смысл в этом? Можно декомпилировать управляемый код и найти вызов. Далее, ковыряем эту нативную DLL, хакаем и подменяем. Все. Да, трудозатраты будут несколько выше, но все равно взломать можно будет.

Comment: Для начала изучите вопрос обфускации. Если покажется мало далее можете еще почитать про самомодифицирующийся код.

Comment: все равно при достаточной мотивации реверсера ничто не остановит

Comment: @iluxa1810 взломать всегда можно будет, это не аргумент. Задача состоит в том, что бы при минимальных трудозатратах программиста создать максимальные сложности для взломщика. Очевидно, что хакнуть нативную длл намного сложнее. + для нативного кода существует полно пакеров, которые преобразуют код в код случайной виртуальной машины. Обфускация .нет кода даже близко не стоит.

Comment: @Zergatul Ну можно разобрать управляемую программу, найти этот вызов и сделать в этом месте, что бы всегда возвращался true. Затем перекомпилировать эти сборки и все. Т.е пока управляемый код на стороне клиента, все легко ломается.

Comment: @Zergatul есть правда всякие подписи. Не знаю, решат ли они задачу компроментации сборки.

Comment: @iluxa1810 нативная длл может возвращать какой-то ключ для расшифровки нужных данных для работы основной программы

Comment: ну вот даже если юзать нативную длл, то её вызов же будет при запуске основного софта, и если смогут декомпилировать его то легко можно отключить вызов этой библиотеки. Мне просто нужно спрятать эту проверку, что бы хотя бы школьник из-за своей невнимательности не смог крякнуть. И обфускации нормальной нет, но если есть у меня неё денег не хватит, а протекторы тоже легко снимаются.